# How to transfer funds from an address to another in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am working on crowdfunding website using the Ethereum blockchain that can create a campaign.
I created an algorithm that creates a payable address, and it can be fundable.

```
function createMyFunDity(string memory _addressName) public checkDuplicateName(_addressName)  {
        address caller  = msg.sender;   
        list_of_creators.push(caller);                                             
     bytes32 hashedAddressName = keccak256(abi.encode(_addressName));
     hashedAddressList.push(hashedAddressName);// added  hashed to the array to comapre . 
     bytes32 hashedString = keccak256(abi.encode(_addressName, msg.sender,block.timestamp));
     address castedAddress = address(uint160(uint256(hashedString)));
     address payable funditeeAddress = payable(castedAddress);
    funditees.push(FunDitees(funditeeAddress,_addressName));
     listOfFunDityAddresses.push(funditeeAddress);
     nameToAddress[_addressName]=funditeeAddress;
     creatorToAddressCreated[caller]=funditeeAddress;
     addressCreatedToCreator[funditeeAddress]=caller;
    

    }
```

The problem right now is  I can't withdraw from the function.

I tried this

```
function withdrawFromAddress( address  payable  _address) public {
        
    uint256 balance = address(_address).balance;
    bool sent =payable(address(this)).send(balance);
    require(sent, "Failed to send ETH");
        
    }
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool sent =payable(address(this)).send(balance);
```

It means transferring `balance` amount of Ether from your contract to your contract.

There are 3 methods to transfer Ether (send, transfer, call), and these all methods transfer Ether from the contract(method caller) to the address.
But it's not possible to transfer from the address to the contract inside the contract except if the address is msg.sender.